# Увеличение значения при каждом вызове функций

Tags: javascript

Как при каждом нажатии на кнопку сохранять значение полученные из функций Aa Ab в блоке summa и увеличивать его на новое полученное?

Я написал такой код.

```js
let edibleGrams;
let carbohydratesInTheProduct;
let weightOfFood;
let breadUnit;
let insulin;

function Aa() { //ФУНКЦИЯ ВЫЗЫВАЕМАЯ ПО КЛИКУ. ПРОИЗВОДИТ РАСЧЕТ грамм продукта КОТОРОЕ можешь употребить на 1ХЕ
  if (document.getElementById('carbohydrateInGrams').value > 0) {

    edibleGrams = 1200 / document.getElementById('carbohydrateInGrams').value;
    document.getElementById('edibleGrams').innerHTML = Math.round(edibleGrams) + ' грамм продукта можешь употребить на 1ХЕ.';
    $('.cb').css('border-bottom', '2px solid #00b7f4');
    $('.col-1').css('border-top', '2px solid #00b7f4');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('edibleGrams').innerHTML = 'Укажите количество углеводов на 100 грамм продукта.';
  }
}

function Ab() { //ФУНКЦИЯ ВЫЗЫВАЕМАЯ ПО КЛИКУ. ПРОИЗВОДИТ РАСЧЕТ углеводов содержется в изделии
  if (document.getElementById('weightOfFood').value > 0 && document.getElementById('carbohydrateInGrams').value > 0) {
    carbohydratesInTheProduct = document.getElementById('carbohydrateInGrams').value * document.getElementById('weightOfFood').value / 100;
    document.getElementById('carbohydratesInTheProduct').innerHTML = Math.round(carbohydratesInTheProduct) + ' углеводов содержется в изделии.';
    
     //вывод ответа по хе в сумму
    document.getElementById('summa').innerHTML = ( document.getElementById('carbohydrateInGrams').value*document.getElementById('weightOfFood').value/100)/12;
          

    breadUnit = (document.getElementById('carbohydrateInGrams').value * document.getElementById('weightOfFood').value / 100) / 12;
    document.getElementById('breadUnit').innerHTML = breadUnit + ' ХЕ содержет это изделие.';

    insulin = carbohydratesInTheProduct / 12;
    document.getElementById('insulin').innerHTML = insulin + ' единиц инсулина нужно поставить';
    $('.cb').css('border-bottom', '2px solid #00b7f4');
    $('.col-1').css('border-top', '2px solid #00b7f4');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('carbohydratesInTheProduct').innerHTML = 'Укажите количество углеводов на 100 грамм продукта и вес продуктового изделия в граммах!';
    document.getElementById('breadUnit').innerHTML = 'Укажите количество углеводов на 100 грамм продукта и вес продуктового  изделия в граммах!';
    $('.cb').css('border-bottom', '2px solid #cc5c5c');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="padding: 10px; color: #000;">
  Cумма ХЕ: <span id="summa"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('summa').textContent = breadUnit;` так не пробовали ?

Comment: `document.getElementById("summa").textContent = breadUnit;`

Comment: это не работает.